# Bootstrap vertically center heading div responsively

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, centering

I am trying to vertically center h5 in a div but I want to do it responsively, so those solutions where you set the parent's height to a certain amount of pixels aren't a solution for me.

The h5 with id "channelName" is what I am trying to vertically center in the parent div.

```
<div class="col-10 text-left channelTab"><h5 id="channelName">Name</h5></div>
```

```css
#greyBox {
  background-color: grey;
}

#title {
  color: white;
}

.logo {
  max-height: 50px;
  max-width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid white;
}

#channelName {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

#channelRow {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4"></div>
    <div id="greyBox" class="col-4 text-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
          <h1 id="title">TITLE</h1>
          <div class="row" id="channelRow">
            <div class="col-2">
              <img src="image.png" class="logo"></div>
            <div class="col-10 text-left channelTab">
              <h5 id="channelName">Name</h5>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-6">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If this could be done more easily with some more changes to my code, any such tips would be welcome as I am really new to this and still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this class to parent of h5 `d-flex align-items-center` and remove bottom margin of `h5`

This class (`d-flex`) will make the display of parent of h5 **flex** and the `align-items-center` will vertically center it.

```css
#greyBox {
  background-color: grey;
}

#title {
  color: white;
}

.logo {
  max-height: 50px;
  max-width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid white;
}

#channelName {
 margin:0;
}

#channelRow {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4"></div>
    <div id="greyBox" class="col-4 text-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
          <h1 id="title">TITLE</h1>
          <div class="row" id="channelRow">
            <div class="col-2">
              <img src="image.png" class="logo"></div>
            <div class="col-10 text-left d-flex align-items-center channelTab">
              <h5 id="channelName">Name</h5>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-6">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works. Just an additional question: What's the logic behind the "margin: 0" ? I can see that the heading wouldn't be perfectly in the center without this, but I don't understand why. Is that because all headings in HTML/Bootstrap have a default margin or something?

Comment: @merkur0 all headings in boostrap have margin-bottom, i just removed it to properly align it vertically